# C++ DLL special characters

Tags: c++, non-ascii-characters

I'm sending an user-generated string from my program into a C++ DLL function I'm making. It works fine, until I send a string like "åäö". My function looks something like this:

```
export void showMessage(char* str) {
    MessageBox(NULL, str, "DLL says", MB_OK);
}
```

When "åäö" is sent from the program, a message with "Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶" popups up. How do I convert it into "åäö"? What library is needed? I'm using Code::Blocks for the DLL.

Comment: There's no reason to make `str` a `char *` instead of a `const char *`. It's functions like this that disallow doing `str.c_str()` as an argument for no good reason. And you should be using the wide version of `MessageBox` if you want Unicode characters.

Comment: That is indeed utf-8.  Not the system code page that MessageBoxA() or the utf-16 string that MessageBoxW() needs.  Use MultiByteToWideString() to make the latter work.

Answer (score 2):

The characters you are using appear to be in the extended ASCII table (value greater than 127), and will depend on the code page you are using, which is a less than portable approach, since the system running your code needs to make environment changes outside of the program itself.

Instead of using `MessageBox`, use the Unicode enabled version, `MessageBoxW`, and look up the Unicode encodings for the characters you specified.

**References**

---

1. *Unicode Versions and ANSI Versions of Functions*, Accessed 2014-06-06, [`<http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvexcodeconcepts/unicode_ansi_version_functs/>`](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvexcodeconcepts/unicode_ansi_version_functs/)
2. *ASCII Table Lookup*, Accessed 2014-06-06, [`<http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/capital-letter-a-ring-uppercase-ascii-code-143.html>`](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/capital-letter-a-ring-uppercase-ascii-code-143.html)
3. *Unicode Lookup*, Accessed 2014-06-06, [`<http://unicodelookup.com/>`](http://unicodelookup.com/)